# finding birthday and store the object into session

Tags: php, session, cookies, mysqli

hello all i am trying to find the recent birthday of the registered members on the site and also store the result of query into session so that next time the query need not to be executed so to reduce the page load time and also server load

i am having this code

```
   if(!isset($_SESSION['dob']) || $_SESSION['dob'] =='' ){
   $frndlist=$_SESSION['friendlist']; //comma seperated list of friends
   $CurrMOnth= date('m'); // this month
   $BirthDLAST0n=date('d', strtotime(' - 7 day')); 
   $BirthDGRATEn=date('d', strtotime(' + 7 day'));
   $GEttheBIrthdaYS=mysqli_query($connection,"select id,name,dob from members
   where (id IN ($frndlist)) and (MONTH(dob) = '$CurrMOnth') and 
   (DAY(dob) > '$BirthDLAST0n' and DAY(dob) < '$BirthDGRATEn' ) 
   order by dob desc limit 10");
   $_SESSION['dob']=$GEttheBIrthdaYS;}else{
   $GEttheBIrthdaYS=$_SESSION['dob'];
   }
   while($theBdaYSreYAr90=mysqli_fetch_array($GEttheBIrthdaYS)){ //print }
```

but the problem here is result of query is stored into session but it is never accepted by the mysqli_fetch_array it says error. 
this is problem because i am trying to store object onto session 
is there any alternative to store the result into something so that the same query need not to be executed gain again ....

and also the birthday script is not good it dosent displays the birthday of people whose DOB is at the last or begning of months.

please let me know how to store the result of query into session or cookie 
as cookie stores very less size i dont think cookie is good option.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to put a whole array into the session var, just break it up.
$result = mysql_fetch_array($GettheBIrthdaYS);
$_SESSION['dob'] = $result['dob'];

Also make your limit 1, unless you want more than 1 record, which if you do then you will need to change everything.

Comment: i want more than 1 record ... atleast 10

Comment: then loop through each variable, save it to an array (array_push) then save that var to a session :)